# Find first record before or after missing record in one table

Tags: sql

I have only one big table Samples with columns Id and Values.
I need get only one record before missing record from table for each gap.
I need help to build query.

Table:

```
Id | Values
---------
1  |  45 
2  |  45 
3  |  44 
5  |  89 
6  |  21 
7  |  59 
9  |  23 
10 |  78 
11 |  12 
12 |  16 
15 |  19
```

Result of query:

```
Id | Values
---------
3  |  44
7  |  59
12 |  16
```

Comment: Tag your database name with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not tagged the database name, you can consider this following logic as generic for any database-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN your_table B ON A.Id = B.Id - 1
WHERE B.Id IS NULL
AND A.Id < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM your_table) 
ORDER BY A.Id
```

If you are using MSSQL 2012 or Newer version, you can use LEAD to achieve your desired output with below script-

```
SELECT A.Id,A.[Values] 
FROM
(
    SELECT *,LEAD(ID) OVER(ORDER BY ID) Lead_Value
    FROM your_table
)A
WHERE Lead_Value- ID >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM   samples s1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT id
                   FROM   samples s2
                   WHERE  s2.id = s1.id + 1)
```

In order to avoid the last row to be selected always you should add:

```
  AND EXISTS (SELECT id
              FROM   samples s3
              WHERE  s3.id > s1.id)
```